# IIF Date falls BETWEEN two dates using SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2016

I am using SSRS 2016 and trying to compare a field to check if the Month falls between two parameters, as following:

```
=IIF(Format(Fields!FromDate.Value, "MMM") BETWEEN (Format(Parameters!FromDate.Value, "MMM") && (Format(Parameters!UnilDate.Value, "MMM") ), Fields!Days.Value, "0")
```

I have manually setup some fields in the dataset to display Jan to Dec. The aim is to show each result in its relevant month when you select the parameters: FromDate and UntilDate

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replicated your scenario on my local report project.

Below is the expression you should try.
Note: What happens when your From date is June 2020 but To date is Aug 2019.
This will work because we are only checking months in between but not Years and so on.

But this should be a starting point for you to update your logic.

```
=IIf(Format(Fields!FromDate.Value, "MM")>= Format(Parameters!FromDate.Value, "MM")
and Format(Fields!FromDate.Value, "MM")<=Format(Parameters!UnilDate.Value, "MM"),
Fields!Days.Value,"0")
```

Edit for only current Year

```
=IIf(Year(Fields!FromDate.Value)>=Year(Parameters!FromDate.Value) and Year(Fields!FromDate.Value)<=Year(Parameters!UnilDate.Value) and Month(Fields!FromDate.Value)>=Month(Parameters!FromDate.Value) and Month(Fields!FromDate.Value)<=Month(Parameters!UnilDate.Value) , Fields!FromDate.Value,"0")
```

Comment: you are right .... need another filter then :( and not sure how to filter that as well?? Would it be changing "MMM" to "MMM-yyyy" ?? by the way, I have edited my post, which gives you more an idea what I need to achieve ...

Comment: I have updated my answer you will get only for current year. I believe you can slowly figure out few other things. If this helps kindly mark this as solved so that it helps others as well.

Comment: will the updates code work per each month? See my topic as I have edited it to make it more sense ... basically, there is a set of columns from January to December, and I like each value to show in each month.... so if you select from 01/01/2019 until 30/06/2019 then the table should show the relevant values and show zero otherwise.

Comment: Yes it will. You had to change slightly as per your specific need

Comment: sorry but it does not work as I intend it to ...  I am happy to demonstrate it to you, if you prefer. not sure if I am allowed to contact you directly?

Comment: @Bucki - If you want to compare dates using a string format, you need to format with year, then month, and then day. `Format(Parameters!FromDate.Value, "yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: @HannoverFist jetzt bin ich total durcheinander mein Freund! See, my aim is to have a static table to show each month from January to December... now, each expression in each column needs to show the total value of each month.  The scenario is to show the total items booked per user & per month. At moment, either I get duplicate figures or some figures do work and some done, or there is #error.  Only way you to understand it is if I demonstrate it to you per a webconference ... not sure if you are willing to participate? ps: yes I am using the format date to compare.

Comment: What exactly is not working for you. Remember you need to go one step at a time. Try to understand the expression what it does. Build small expression visualize result and then jump to another step.

Also my updated 2nd expression will check if parameterFromDate and until date is between Fields!FromDate.Value, if it does it will show that value else it will set 0.

Note. If you add this same expression on each textbox it will only check for Fields!FromDate.Value and not for any other fields you wish to check.

Comment: @AnkUser yes, true the expression does show the value or zero :) but it does same result for each month lol  .True, we need to work step by step but if I mark this as "solved" then topic is closed ....

Comment: I think what you want is for For ex: If parameter from is may and To is july,
Your columns jan to April should be 0, and columns may to july should show value and then from August to december should be 0.

Now if this is the case what is the role of Fields!FromDate.Value
What if your FromDate is Jan?

Comment: @AnkUser I was not able to do it and dropped it :( thanks for your feedback.